# How to recursively merge inherited json array elements?

Tags: json, inheritance, merge, jq, ancestor

I have the following json file named `CMakePresets.json` that is a cmake-preset file:

```
{
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "default",
      "hidden": true,
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/_build/${presetName}",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "YIO_DEV": "1",
        "BUILD_TESTING": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "debug",
      "inherits": "default",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "release",
      "inherits": "default",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/_build/Debug",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "arm",
      "inherits": "debug",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "${sourceDir}/cmake/Toolchain/arm-none-eabi-gcc.cmake"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want recursively merge with `*` the `configurePresets` elements that inherit themselves for a specific entry `name`. I have example a node with name `arm` and want to have resulting json object with resolved inheritance. The parent has the name stored inside `.inherits` of each element. `arm` inherits over `debug` which inherits over `default`.

I could write a bash shell loop that I believe works, with the help of [Remove a key:value from an JSON object using jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48529016/remove-a-keyvalue-from-an-json-object-using-jq) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36218044/9072753):

```
input=arm
# extract one element
g() { jq --arg name "$1" '.configurePresets[] | select(.name == $name)' CMakePresets.json; };
# get arm element
acc=$(g "$input");
# If .inherits field exists
while i=$(<<<"$acc" jq -r .inherits) && [[ -n "$i" && "$i" != "null" ]]; do
   # remove it from input
   a=$(<<<"$acc" jq 'del(.inherits)');
   # get parent element
   b=$(g "$i");
   # merge parent with current
   acc=$(printf "%s\n" "$b" "$a" | jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)');
done;
echo "$acc"
```

outputs, which I believe is the expected output for `arm`:

```
{
  "name": "arm",
  "hidden": true,
  "generator": "Ninja",
  "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/_build/${presetName}",
  "cacheVariables": {
    "YIO_DEV": "1",
    "BUILD_TESTING": "1",
    "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
    "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE": "${sourceDir}/cmake/Toolchain/arm-none-eabi-gcc.cmake"
  }
}
```

But I want to write it in `jq`. I tried and `jq` language is not intuitive for me. I can do it for example for two (ie. countable) elements:

```
< CMakePresets.json jq --arg name "arm" '
   def g(n): .configurePresets[] | select(.name == n);
   g($name) * (g($name) | .inherits) as $name2 | g($name2)
'
```

But I do not know how to do `reduce .[] as $item ({}; . * $item)` when the `$item` is really `g($name)` that depends on the last `g($name) | .inherits`. I tried reading [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) and learning about variables and loops, but `jq` has a very different syntax. I tried to use `while`, but that's just syntax error that I do not understand and do not know how to fix. I guess `while` and `until` might not be right here, as they operate on previous loop output, while the elements are always from root.

```
$ < CMakePresets.json jq --arg name "arm" 'def g(n): .configurePresets[] | select(.name == n);
while(g($name) | .inherits as $name; g($name))   
'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting '|' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 2:
while(g($name) | .inherits as $name; g($name))                                      
jq: 1 compile error
```

How to write such loop in `jq` language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the inheritance hierarchy contains no loops, as is the case with the example, we can break the problem down into the pieces shown below:

```
# Use an inner function of arity 0 to take advantage of jq's TCO
def inherits_from($dict):
  def from:
    if .name == "default" then .
    else $dict[.inherits] as $next
    | ., ($next | from)
    end;
  from;

def chain($start):
  INDEX(.configurePresets[]; .name) as $dict
  | $dict[$start] | inherits_from($dict);

reduce chain("arm") as $x (null;
  ($x.cacheVariables + .cacheVariables) as $cv
  | $x + .
  | .cacheVariables = $cv)
| del(.inherits)
```

This produces the desired output efficiently.

One advantage of the above formulation of a solution is that it can easily be modified to handle circular dependencies.

### Using `recurse/1`

`inherits_from/1` could also be defined using the built-in function `recurse/1`:

```
def inherits_from($dict):
  recurse( select(.name != "default") | $dict[.inherits]) ;
```

or perhaps more interestingly:

```
def inherits_from($dict):
  recurse( select(.inherits) | $dict[.inherits]) ;
```

#### Using `*`

Using `*` to combine objects has a high overhead because of its recursive semantics, which is often either not required or not wanted.  However,
if it is acceptable here to use `*` for combining the objects, the above can be simplified to:

```
def inherits_from($dict):
  recurse( select(.inherits) | $dict[.inherits]) ;

INDEX(.configurePresets[]; .name) as $dict
| $dict["arm"] 
| reduce inherits_from($dict) as $x ({};  $x * .)
| del(.inherits)
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing a recursive function is actually simple, once you get the hang of it:

```
jq --arg name "$1" '
    def _get_in(input; n):
        (input[] | select(.name == n)) |
        (if .inherits then .inherits as $n | _get_in(input; $n) else {} end) * .;
    def get(name):
        .configurePresets as $input | _get_in($input; name);
    get($name)
' "$presetfile"
```

First I filter only `.configurePresets` then in a function I get `input[] |  select(.name == n)` only the part I am interested in. Then `if .inherits` if it has inherits, then `.inherits as $n | _get_in(input; $n)` take the name in inherits and call itself again. Else return `else {} end` empty. Then that is `* .` merged with the result of `input[] | select(.name == n)` - the itself. So it recursively loads all the `{} * (input[]|select()) * (input[]|select()) * (input[]|select())`.

Comment: This solution is rather inefficient: (a) `input[] | select(.name == n)` vs having a lookup table; (b) in jq it is generally preferable to avoid having functions of arity greater than 0 calling themselves directly.

Comment: A stylistic point: since `input/0` is a built-in function, it would be better not to use "input" as a named argument in a `def`.